# GoLang fmt.Scan type error skip next fmt.Scan

Tags: go

Am a beginner of GoLang here is a sample code from a tutorial.

```golang
func main() {
    for {
        var name string
        var email string
        var userTickets uint
        // ask user for info
        fmt.Println("Input your Name please")
        fmt.Scan(&name)

        fmt.Println("Input your Email please")
        fmt.Scan(&email)

        // ask user for number of tickets
        fmt.Println("Input number of ticket")
        if _, err := fmt.Scanln(&userTickets); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an interesting thing I found:
if I entered "-1" in "Input number of ticket". It will throw an error since userTickets is uint. With that err it will also put an "enter/next line" for "Input your Name please" in the next loop.
The result would look like this

```
Input your Name please
Test
Input your Email please
Test
Input number of tickect
-1
expected integer
Input your Name please <= this input is skipped
Input your Email please
```

So just wondering why this heppened? How can I resolve that (without changing type from uint to int)?

Comment: If you type in `-1` then `-` causes the `fmt.Scanln(&userTicket)` to exit with error, the next `fmt.Scan(&name)` statement doesn't block because it is fed the remaining input, i.e. `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your comment plus @Volker's answers solved my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So just wondering why this heppened?

Because -1 cannot be stored in an uint.

> How can I resolve that (without changing type from uint to int)?

You cannot.

(The right thing to do is not to use fmt.Scan but to always read whole lines into a string and parse the string.)

Comment: I know -1 cannot be stored in an uint, could you please confirm the comment from @mkopriva is correct? "If you type in -1 then - causes the fmt.Scanln(&userTicket) to exit with error, the next fmt.Scan(&name) statement doesn't block because it is fed the remaining input, i.e. 1." . My understanding on his comment is ticket scan take "-" and scan for first name take rest of "1"

Comment: Ah, I can confirm @mkopriva was correct, fmt.Scan(&name) statement doesn't block because it is fed the remaining input, i.e. 1